# How to resubmit google play after being rejected?

Tags: google-play-console

I really cannot find the page for resubmitting. It seems they updated the dashboard recently that the previous answers here don't match to find the resubmitting page. Do I have to click "Created new release"? or is there somewhere the button of Resubmit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it's just the same way as update a new version unless you have to change an important answer to the previous question.

[image: Click to see screenshot]

**How to do resubmit**

```
Choose the app which is rejected.
Then Click Production.
Then Create new release
Then change the version at your build.gradle 
(You cannot use the same version. Just change the number)
Then Upload your new apk
```